# Marginal convergence with independence implies jointly convergence

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

If $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent random vectors for every $n$, then $X_n \overset{d}{\to} X$ and $Y_n \overset{d}{\to}Y$ imply that $(X_n,Y_n) \overset{d}{\to} (X,Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

I know the statement is true for $X_n, Y_n$ converges to $X, Y$ in probability without the assumption of independence. When I tried to prove this, I used the characteristic function, but I got stuck to show $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: You are not asked to prove that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 8):

Counterexample to what you are trying to prove:
Let $X_1,Y_1,X_2,Y_2,\cdots$ be i.i.d. random variables with standard normal distribution. Then $X_n \to X_1$ in distribution and $Y_n \to X_1$ in distribution. Even though $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent for each $n$ it is not true that $X_1$ is independent of itself!.

The hypothesis that $X_n \overset {d} {\to} X$ does not determine  a random variable $X$. The fact remains true if you replace $X$ by another random variable with the same distribution. So there is no question of proving that $X$ and $Y$ are independent (since we don't even know what those random variables are). You are supposed to assume that $X$ and $Y$  are independent (so that their joint distribution is uniquely defined) and then prove that $(X_n,Y_n)$ converges to $(X,Y)$ in distribution. Now use the answer by Will M.

Comment: I could be like really wrong (I am just a student of probability), but I believe that $X$ is independent of $Y$ can be proven if one bears in mind measure language (so one proves that the limit measure can be decomposed as the product of two marginal measures).

Comment: @WillM. It appears that you have some basic confusions with joint distributions and convergence in distribution. I have provided a counterexample to show that $X$ and $Y$ need not be independent.

Comment: Right, but $(X_n, Y_n)$ will converge weakly to some vector $Z$ that is normal with mean zero and covariance matrix $I_2.$

Comment: @WillM. What is true is: $X$ and $Y$ can be chosen to be independent. You cannot prove them to be independent.

Comment: Mmm, I think that when dealing with weak convergence, one is dealing with measures as opposed to the "random variables." However, whatever the weak-limits $Z$ of $(X_n, Y_n)$ may be, it will satisfay that $\mu_Z(A \times B) = \alpha(A) \beta(B)$ for some probability measures $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and this is what the exercise is asking.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $Ee^{i((X_n, Y_n) \mid (u, v))} = Ee^{i (uX_n + v Y_n)}=Ee^{iu X_n} Ee^{i vY_n}$, now let $n \to \infty.$

Comment: That's what I tried, but after letting $n \to \infty$, you only have $Ee^{iu X_n} Ee^{i vY_n}\to Ee^{iuX}Ee^{ivY}$, how could you cliam $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: The left hand side converes to $Ee^{i((X, Y) \mid (u,v))}$ because $f(X, Y) =e^{i((X, Y) \mid (u,v))}$ is continuous and bounded. What definition of weak-convergence are you using?

Comment: I know the continuity theorem, but your statement does not make sense since we only have marginal convergence.

Comment: Okay, what you know is that $(X_n,Y_n)$ converges weakly to some random vector $Z = (Z_1, Z_2)$ and you know that the random vector $Z$ satisfies $Ee^{i(Z\mid (u,v))} = Ee^{i u X} Ee^{i u Y}.$ This shows $Z_1 \sim X$ and $Z_2 \sim Y$ and $Z_1$ is independent of $Z_2.$

Comment: In words: you are showing that the weak-limit of $(X_n, Y_n)$ is a random vector whose entries are independent; rephrasing in terms of measures, what you are showing is that the sequences of measures $\mu_{(X_n, Y_n)}$ converges to a measure $\tau$ such that $\tau(A \times B) = \alpha(A) \beta(B)$ for two measures $\alpha$ and $\beta.$

Comment: Okay, here is the issue, we only have $X_n \to X$ and $Y_n \to Y$ weakly, what we want to show is $(X_n, Y_n) \to (X, Y)$ in distribution jointly. From your statement, only have $Ee^{i(u v)(X_n Y_n)} \to Ee^{iuX}Ee^{ivY}$ and this does not imply $(X_n, Y_n) \to (X, Y).$

Comment: Oops, I think I get your point now. Sorry,  the ch. function of $Z$ is $Ee^{iuX}Ee^{ivY}$ which has already been written as a product of two ch. functions.

Comment: @RuixuanZhang so you agree that you can prove that the pair $(X_n, Y_n)$ converges weakly to some random pair $(X, Y)$ and that this random pair $(X, Y)$ satisfies $X$ and $Y$ are independent? After thinking for a bit more, I think the "counter-example" given above is nothing as convergence of the pair $(X_n, Y_n)$ to $(X, Y)$ is _not equivalent_ to the convergence of $X_n$ to $X$ and $Y_n$ to $Y.$