# $X_n\Rightarrow X$, $Y_n\Rightarrow Y$ and $X_n$ & $Y_n$ are independent implies $X$ & $Y$ are independent?

Tags: probability, independence, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent for all $n\geq 1$, and
$$X_n\Rightarrow X$$
and
$$Y_n\Rightarrow Y$$
as $n\to\infty$, where "$\Rightarrow$" means the convergence in distribution.

Is that right: $X$ and $Y$ are independent? How to prove?

Thank you!

Comment: Convergence in distribution?  Then you can replace $Y$ by anything with the same distribution as $Y$; in particular, something dependent on $X$.  Perhaps you mean some other mode of convergence.

Comment: No, it is not true, look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3109685/marginal-convergence-with-independence-implies-jointly-convergence).